# Jenkins not able to deploy to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3

I am trying to run deployment using Jenkins and my pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Prepare build repo') {
            steps {
                echo 'Cleanup test'
                sh 'sudo git clean -fdx'
                git([url: 'git@github.com:Myapp/infrastructure.git', branch: '${API_COMMIT}', credentialsId: 'myappawsdeployment'])
            }
        }
        stage('Update env config') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        withCredentials(
                        [
                            string(credentialsId: 'vault-token', variable: 'token'),
                            string(credentialsId: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', variable: 'aws_access_key_id'),
                            string(credentialsId: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', variable: 'aws_secret_access_key'),
                            [$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'myapp_aws_jenkins_staging', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                        ]) {
                            sshagent(['myappjenkins']) {
                              sh """
                              set -ex
                              export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${aws_access_key_id}
                              export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${aws_secret_access_key}
                              export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
                              export VAULT_TOKEN=${token}
                              cd app/myapp/atest
                              helm init --client-only --skip-refresh
                              helm repo rm stable
                              helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable 
                              helm plugin install https://github.com/hypnoglow/helm-s3.git || true
                              helm repo add myapp s3://helm-chart-repository
                              make install COMMIT=$API_COMMIT BUILD_ID=$BUILD_ID
                              """
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(error) {
                        throw error
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see this error:

```
+ helm repo add myapp s3://helm-chart-repository
fetch from s3 uri=s3://helm-chart-repository/index.yaml: fetch object from s3: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: 5045C78BE1BD8BAF, host id: vico0IkS1ZE9bnSPpaMwWwkQmTRSvWYtaRMMxE1hKTE/XLXvcazX+hPS/dqyeusqkuok200Q00s=
Error: Looks like "s3://helm-chart-repository" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: plugin "bin/helms3" exited with error
```

I am not sure why this fails, because I am extracting AWS key and secret for it.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not mention the policy which is attached to the user whose credentials you are using in `Jenkinsfile`. Following policy the `username` user must-have.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListObjects",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/username"]
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-helm-charts"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowObjectsFetchAndCreate",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/username"]
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-helm-charts/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

On top of that make sure your `S3 Bucket` Policy also must be allowing for this user access.

[How to create a Helm chart repository using Amazon S3](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-create-a-helm-chart-repository-using-amazon-s3/)